# Storing Api key in .env file and using it in a React component inside a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to use an api key as a variable by including it in a link for a get request.
In the code snippet below the key is saved in the variable correctly and, also, if I console.log it I can see it in the console. However, somehow, if I insert the variable in the link inside the get request, it doesn't work anymore and doesn't retrieve any data. Could you please explain me why and what I have to do differently?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default function Chart(props) {

    const [hourlyData, setHourlyData] = useState([]);

    const coordinates = props.savedCoordinates;

    const API_Key = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY
    
    console.log(API_Key)

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coordinates.lat}&lon=${coordinates.lon}&exclude=current,minutely,daily,alerts&appid=${API_Key}`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    })
```

Edit: More info

This is the content of my .env file

```
REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY={my api key}
```

Also the .env file is located at the root of the folder and I restarted the server after creating the file

Comment: In your network tab when you fire this API call did you check whether the API_Key is getting appended to the url ?

Comment: In the console I get an error 401 and I can see that the key is appended to the url of the get request.

Comment: Then i would suggest you to check in the backend . Looks like a backend issue .

Comment: I don't have a backend. It's just a frontend weather app that retrieves data from the open weather map API

Answer (score -1):

After making an update to your.env file, did you restart your development server? And can you share how you added the content in your .env file? And make sure your .env file is at the root of your project.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server and this is the content of my .env file REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY={key number here}